# Security Trimming

Tags: 2013, custom-list

We would like to use search filtering to provide a custom master page to users with almost everything they will need to do to start their jobs.

I have a list that has Department codes and would like to filter and provide a user a main master page with links to items they will need for day to day work.

How can this be completed in SP 2013 Standard?

Comment: I'm not certain security trimming, doing row permissions keyed to a list would be the way to go here.  Likely I would use managed metadata to use managed metadata your navigation, and set up permissions for each link in each "keyword".

Comment: Actually didn't see the catch on "standard edition" which can't do metadata for navigation.  In this case I'd consider building a web part to key to a list of Departments in one column, URL's in another column.  Offhand the only way I can think of.

Comment: Thank for the helpful info